# Choose which program to open file with

Tags: java, windows, swing, file-io

My program comes with a sister program that I want to use to open a file. 
`Desktop.open(file)` will not work as it only opens the default program, not the sister program.

Comment: Can you pass the file path as a command line parameter to the sister program?

Comment: Either create a new instance of the "sister" program within the current JVM or use something like `ProcessBuilder` to execute it, passing the "file" as a command line argument.  Or change the default program

Comment: @copeg Yes, but I don't know how to close the command line after it's opened the sister program.

Comment: @Jayjey If you use something like `ProcessBuilder` to execute the sister program, when it (the sister program) is closed, it will terminate the process by itself